# Prevent left navigation menu to be refreshed with Response.Redirect()

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, asp.net-ajax

I have my left navigation menu is on my master page and and i am using update panel also, my problem is whenever I call to Response.Redirect() the entire page is getting refreshed and the left navigation menu's status is getting flushed out every time. I need to maintain the left navigation menu's status.

Comment: please post some code , better of the structure of your left menu.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010887/reload-a-page-without-reloading-the-masterpage

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use framesets, or build an Ajax driven website, the standard way to handle this is  to implement a sitemap for your website so that the left hand nav knows what state to display when it loads each page.

Comment: +1 for the site map suggestion, ooh I forgot that we use it for a while :)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you will need to run a javascript/jQuery code on page load.

you will run this code to get the current page name/title/anything that you can use to differentiate between your pages, then you will use this value to update the left menu item that points to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do that.

1.use frame

```
<html>
......
<body>
<frame>left menu</frame>
<frame>right</frame>
</body>
</html>
```

redirect right frame.

2.use ajax and div/frame

```
<html>
......
<body>
<div>left menu</div>
<div>right</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use ajax(try jquery) to update right div.